# Proxy not working as expected

Tags: javascript, oop, object

Recently, I've been trying to learn metaprogramming in javaScript. However, this script writes

```
false
true
```

to the console when I'd expect it to write `true` twice:

```js
var foo = new Proxy({x:20,y:20},{
  has: function(target, prop) {
    console.log(target.hasOwnProperty(prop)) //false
    if(target.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      return true; 
    }
    return false; //gets returned???
  }
});

console.log('toString' in foo) //true
```

**Note**: People have replied saying it shows `false` twice and that that's as expected. I'm getting `false` then `true` using vanilla Safari, 10.1.2, no extensions except disabled Flash and Java:

[image]

Comment: Vanilla Safari, 10.1.2, no extensions except disabled Flash and Java.
I felt that it was implied I was somehow trolling since I received two downvotes for what I had thought was a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: I can confirm it happens in Safari on iOS v11 as well. Now **that's** interesting.

Comment: FWIW, I've updated my answer with details about what *should* be happening. As far as I can tell, Safari is just getting this wrong by not letting you return `false` for that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's very interesting indeed that Safari shows you `false` then `true`. (I can verify that it shows me that, too, in iOS Safari on iOS v11.2.6.) `in` uses the abstract [HasProperty](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-hasproperty) operation, which uses the [[HasProperty]] internal operation of the object you use it on (in your case, the proxy). The [steps for the [[HasProperty]] operation for Proxy objects](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-hasproperty-p) **do** allow the result to be different from what your handler returned if your handler returns `false`, but the additional checks that would make that happen don't apply to your code. Specifically: A `has` handler isn't allowed to say the property doesn't exist if it exists as an "own" property on the target and either 1) that property is not configurable, or 2) the object isn't extensible. Your target object doesn't have an own `toString` property, so that doesn't apply. So it looks like Safari may be getting those checks slightly wrong. Looking at the snapshot specs ES2015, ES2016, and ES2017, this behavior hasn't changed since proxies were introduced.

FWIW, it should output `false` twice, because:

- `target` doesn't have its **own** property called `toString` (it inherits it from `Object.prototype`), so the `console.log(target.hasOwnProperty(prop));` correctly shows `false`.
- Because your proxy returns the result of `hasOwnProperty` (somewhat indirectly), the `console.log('toString' in foo);` also correctly shows `false`.

If you wanted to just have `has` perform its normal behavior, the best way to do that is probably to use [`Reflect.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/has):

```js
var foo = new Proxy({x:20,y:20},{
  has: function(target, prop) {
    var flag = Reflect.has(target, prop);
    console.log(flag); // true
    return flag;
  }
});

console.log('toString' in foo) // true
```

...or of course, you could use `in`:

```js
var foo = new Proxy({x:20,y:20},{
  has: function(target, prop) {
    var flag = prop in target;
    console.log(flag); // true
    return flag;
  }
});

console.log('toString' in foo) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

i got `false` twice

```js
var foo = new Proxy({x:20,y:20},{
  has: function(target, prop) {
    console.log(target.hasOwnProperty(prop)) 
    if(target.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      return true; 
    }
    return false; 
  }
});
console.log('toString' in foo);
console.log('x' in foo)
```

If you run `console.log('x' in foo)`,you got twice `true` because `x` property exists in `{x:20,y:20}` while `toString` exists in `Object.prototype`.

And that is why

```js
let obj={x:20,y:20};
console.log('x' in obj);//true
console.log('toString' in obj);//true
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));//['x','y']
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('x'));//true
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('y'));//true
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('toString'));//false
```